# Push Multiple Values to Array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

If I have a element with multiple values inside a data-attr, how can I add those **individually** to a array?

```
<button id="test" data-values="1 13513 51681">TEST</button>
```

… and this:

```
$('#test').on('click',function(){
  myArr.push($(this).data('values'));
  console.log(myArr)
});
```

… gives me: `["1 13513 51681"]`.

But I need: `["1","13513","51681"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function that will return you the array straightaway.

```
$('#test').on('click',function(){
   myArr = $(this).data('values').split(' ');
   console.log(myArr)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` in javascript it gives in array what you expected

```
$('#test').on('click',function(){
    myArr = $(this).data('values').split(" ");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not splitted the string so you cant access all values in array, you will get only one element due to that like `1 13513 51681`. So use  following

```
$('#test').on('click',function(){
  myArr = $(this).data('values').split(' ');
  myArr.push($(this).data('values'));
  console.log(myArr)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataarry=[entityid,domainid,'entityid_domainid',filetemplate]
function filetemplateremove(entityid, domainid) {
      var removeItem = entityid + "_" + domainid;                          
      dataarry.splice(dataarry.indexOf(removeItem), 1);
}
```

Comment: You need to explain the code that you have shared. Sharing the code is not enough.